# How to mock a sequelize transaction with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

## Scenario

I have the following type of function that I wish to test. This function has

### File to be tested

```js
export const doSomething = () => {

    sequelize.transaction(async t => {
        customModel.upsert(dataObject, { transaction : t })
        
        otherCustomModel.upsert(otherDataObject, { transaction : t })
    })
    
}
```

Here `customModel` and `otherCustomModel` are valid models written using `sequelize.define` in their respective files.

Here `sequelize` is the following thing

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const connectionParams = {
// assume valid config is present
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionParams);

(async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Sequelize authenticated successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Unable to connect to the database: ${error}`);
    }
})();

export default sequelize;
```

## Requirements

I wish to write a testcase with the following checks:

1. Test that the following functions are called once.

   - `transaction`
   - `customModel.upsert`
   - `otherCustomModel.upsert`
2. The entire function executes

How can I go ahead and mock a sequelize transaction using jest for such functions?

---

### My Test

```js
test("text", () => {
    
    // mocks
    sequelize.transaction = jest.fn()
    customModel.upsert = jest.fn()
    otherCustomModel.upsert = jest.fn()
 

    doSomething()

    // assertions
    expect(sequelize.transaction).toBeCalled();
    expect(customModel.upsert).toBeCalled();
    expect(otherCustomModel.upsert).toBeCalled();

})
```

### Error Faced

```bash
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

62 |        expect(sequelize.transaction).toBeCalled();
```

### Versions

| S No. | Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sequelize | ^6.19.1 |
| 2 | jest | ^27.5.1 |

---

**P.S.** : Any other suggestions to enhance my test case are welcomed!

Comment: What have you tried? What problems you're facing? Are you looking for a general approach?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Teneff/jest-workshop/blob/tests/advanced/02-transaction-wrap/index.spec.js) it's somewhat similar example

Comment: @Teneff I have updated my question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I would write it something like this

```js
describe('doSomething', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    doSomething()
  })

  it('should call transaction with a callback', () => {
    expect(sequalize.transaction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.any(Function)
    )
  })

  describe('the transaction', () => {
    let mockTransaction = { prop: 'dummy transaction object' }
    
    beforeAll(() => {
      const transactionCallback = sequalize.transaction.mock.calls[0][0]
      transactionCallback(mockTransaction)
      // presuming you're NOT using jest.spyOn on sequalize.transaction
      // you have to call the callback passed to it
    })

    it('should have called customModel.upsert', () => {
      const dataObject = expect.objectContaining({
        // ...expected properties
      })
      expect(customModel.upsert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        dataObject, { transaction : mockTransaction }
      );
    })

    it.todo('should have called otherCustomModel.upsert ... same as above')
  })
})
```

Comment: I shall try this and get back to you if it works for me. Thnak you. This does seem promising.

Comment: @TanishqVyas also make sure to check the example I've given you in the comment above

Comment: This results is `ReferenceError: sequalize is not defined` error. Is there anything that I ned to do in trms of mocking sequellize or something because I have imported it on the top of my file correctly.

Comment: @TanishqVyas just edit your question to show how you've included and mocked it, otherwise it would be a wild guess

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do it e.g. like this:

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const customModel = require('<your module>');
const otherCustomModel = require('<your module>');

jest.mock('sequelize', () => ({
    transaction: jest.fn(() => jest.fn()),
}));
jest.spyOn(customModel, 'upsert');
jest.spyOn(otherCustomModel, 'upsert');
```

And in you test case:

```
sequelize.transaction.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
otherCustomModel.upsert.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
customModel.upsert.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
```

and after that you can do your assertions e.g.:

```
expect(sequelize.transaction).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: I do not care for the current implementation of the models while mocking them. However the transaction's implementation is what's causing the issue.